# Stacking variables with jade / pug

Tags: pug

I'm relatively new to Jade / Pug and i've been having some trouble with a mixin. I used the jade documentation to create the following, which works when I compile with Codekit.

**Mixin:**

```
mixin svg(svg_file, svg_id, svg_class, svg_title)
  svg(class="#{svg_class}",aria-hidden='true', title="#{svg_title}")
    use(xlink:href="img/sprites/#{svg_file}##{svg_id}")
```

**Instance:**

```
+svg("media.svg", "location", "sm", "My Location")
```

**Output:**

```
<svg class="sm" aria-hidden="true" title="My Location">
  <use xlink:href="img/sprites/media.svg#location"></use>
</svg>
```

Unfortunately compiling these files elsewhere, with a gulp task, or on Codepen doesn't seem to have the same output. I'm seeing things like `#{svg_file}` instead of the `media.svg` i'd expect to come through.

In the pug documentation the [mixin attributes](https://pugjs.org/language/mixins.html#mixin-attributes) section provides the following sample:

```
mixin link(href, name)
  a(href=href)&attributes(attributes)= name
```

My question is, how would I use that syntax to stack my variables like I 
did with jade:

`#{svg_file}##{svg_id}`

to end up with:

`media.svg#location`

Answer (score 2):

Pug supports [Attribute Interpolation](https://pugjs.org/api/migration-v2.html#attribute-interpolation) for this type of situation

The syntax for the mixin mentioned above, in this case, could be:

```
mixin svg(svg_file, svg_id, svg_class, svg_title)
  span.icon
    svg(class=svg_class, aria-hidden='true', title=svg_title)
      use(xlink:href= svg_file + '#' + svg_id)
```